# Nativescript launch screen logo tiny

Tags: nativescript

I used the new Nativescript Sidekick feature to create my launch screens, but the logo appears tiny on the screen. To fix it to make it look more like the stock nativescript logo size, I manually modified and replaced the logo in App Resources files generated to more closely match those images, but regardless my logo continues to look very small on the launch screen. Where is that sizing controlled? If I look in splash_screen.xml I don't see anything that controls the size for android.

Comment: You might have to adjust the `gravity` of logo in the `splash_screen.xml` file.

Comment: I can set it to fill instead of center, but my logo gets stretched. All of this seems so non-intuitive. Are there other values to use? And why does the blank nativescript template from Sidekick work so well? I've tried to create my logos to look the same in size and have used the actual pngs provided to make sure my aspects are the same?

Comment: You could specify a width and height on the `item` containing the `logo` bitmap.

Comment: What about if my logo is MASSIVE? I can't find any documentation on how to adjust the size.